# Why doesn't my "SharedPreferences" work?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

The Problem is, that the Text field which is in "Wizard2Activity" just shows "nothing" and not what the user has typed in the "EditText" in "Wizard1".

Wizard1.java:

```
package com.CENSORED.CENSORED;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Wizard1 extends Activity {

public static final String PREFS ="examplePrefs";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wizard1);


final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);


Button nextAct = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

nextAct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

    String message = et.getText().toString();   

    SharedPreferences examplePrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
    Editor editor = examplePrefs.edit();
    editor.putString("usermessage", message);
    editor.commit();

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),         
  Wizard2Activity.class);
    startActivity(i);

}


});


}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is   

    present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.wizard1, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);



}


}
```

And Wizard 2 Activity:

```
package com.CENSORED.CENSORED;

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Wizard2Activity extends Activity {

public static final String PREFS ="examplePrefs";






@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wizard2);


    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    SharedPreferences example = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);

    String userString = example.getString("userMessage", "nothing");

    tv.setText(userString);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is   
present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.wizard2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change

```
String userString = example.getString("userMessage", "nothing");
```

to

```
String userString = example.getString("usermessage", "nothing");
```

key is `usermessage`. It's just typo.

Comment: Omg! Thank you bro, the Key was really the Problem! ;)

Comment: @AndroidDev, if an answer has helped you, you should _accept_ it by clicking the check mark next to it :-)

Comment: Thank you for mentioning it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the method

```
editor.putString("usermessage", message);
```

and

```
example.getString("userMessage", "nothing");
```

have different key.

Comment: @AndroidDev I hope you learned a lesson from this. Start putting keys into a class specifically designed for this and make the keys public static final so you can access them from anywhere